# Can rollback after providing the commit operation

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to rollback the deleted records which are commited as my procedure has deleted the records from the table.

```
Delete from TC_trans;
Commit;
```

Now i want to retrieve it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you can issue a flashback query to retrieve the deleted record. Example is given below for your reference. Please check if the corresponding records are retrieved after issuing this query.

## Example:

```
insert into v (select * from v as of timestamp(systimestamp - interval '60' minute));
```

You can also issue a minus query as given below.

```
insert into v (select * from v as of timestamp(systimestamp - interval '60' minute)) minus select * from v;
```

Please read the complete flashback statements to understand the concept. Thank you.

Reference : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_fl.htm

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. With `COMMIT` you've decided *not* to roll back, but commit.

You may be able however to access the deleted data and thus rescue it with a flashback query. E.g.:

```
select * from tc_trans as of timestamp systimestamp - 0.1;
```

More on flashback queries here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr002.htm.